# Logstash Array split gives Nilclass for one element array

Tags: elasticsearch, split, logstash

I am trying to input json data from logs through filebeat-> logstash  to elasticsearch but i seem to get NilClass error no matter what i try.

The data sample:

```
{"student":[{"details":{"name":chirs,"lname":dave},"age":10,"grade":1.2,"id":"323"}],"id":"metric95"}
```

my logstash configuration is:

```
input {
    beats {
        port => "5044"
    }
}
filter {
json {
    source => "message"
  }
 split {
      field => "[student]"
    }
}
output {
elasticsearch {
        hosts => [ "localhost:9200" ]
    }

    stdout { codec => rubydebug }
} 

Error:  split - Only String and Array types are splittable. field:[student] is of type = NilClass
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try

```
split {
  field => "student"
}
```

and put double quotes as `{"name":"chirs","lname":"dave"}`